# Use SVG images as images for video editor

Tags: image, video-sequence-editor

I am using Blender video editing capabilities to edit a video. However, when I need to add a text, I find Blender misses a lot of stuff, like for example aligning the text. What I am doing is working in parallel with Inkscape to create images for my titles and text. I export my svg as a png and import that into Blender.

Is it possible to avoid exporting to png? It would be easier to just import the svg as an image, so if I update the svg file, I get the results directly in Blender.

Comment: I think that you cannot import an svg directly into the video sequencer. Maybe, you can create your titles in 3D view or GreasePencil and add the scene to the video sequencer (of another scene). That way, they can be reloaded automatically when changed.

Comment: You can import SVG from the menu File->Import->Scalable Vector Graphics but it will only be useful in the 3D viewport. If you're planning to use it as a mask in the Video Sequencer using the Image Editor or Movie Clip Editor, you'll have to trace the text (image or movie) in Mask mode.